# Idiomatic exception handling for socket connection

Tags: scala, sockets, error-handling, functional-programming, try-with-resources

I'm trying to understand how I can elegantly use `scala.util.control.Exception` package.

To be more specific I want to convert this piece of Java code to functional way:

```
public static boolean hostAvailabilityCheck() { 
    try (Socket s = new Socket(SERVER_ADDRESS, TCP_SERVER_PORT)) {
        return true;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        /* ignore */
    }
    return false;
}
```

I can do same in Scala using try-catch-finally, but I'm looking for more functional way. Please also note that this Java code uses `try-with-resources`, so it's mean this code anyway will close the socket (even if exception occurs): `socket.close()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**---EDIT upon question clarification---**

To use automatic resource management in a functional style in scala, the easiest way would be to use [scala-arm](http://jsuereth.com/scala-arm/usage.html) then you can write

```
import resource._

def hostAvailabilityCheck():Boolean= { 
  managed(new Socket(SERVER_ADDRESS, TCP_SERVER_PORT)).map(_=>true).opt.isDefined
}
```

---

If you really, really want to use `scala.util.control.Exception` you could write :

```
import scala.util.control.Exception._
def hostAvailabilityCheck():Boolean= { 
  catching[IOException].opt(new Socket(SERVER_ADDRESS, TCP_SERVER_PORT)). isDefined
}
return false;
```

}

Even better, you can use the [`Try`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.util.Try) type to do this, in which case your original method would become :

```
def hostAvailabilityCheck():Boolean = { 
  Try(new Socket(SERVER_ADDRESS, TCP_SERVER_PORT)).isSuccess
}
```

It isn't clear from your example what you want to do with this, but it could possibly be useful to return the `Try` instead of a Boolean, this way if the port acquisition succeeded you don't have to wait for port recycling at the OS level before rebinding to it in a more definitive way.

```
def hostAvailabilityCheck(port: Int):Try[Socket] = { 
  Try(new Socket(SERVER_ADDRESS, port))
}
```

Then your client code could try to acquire a port until it actually gets one :

```
def acquire(port: Int):Socket={
  hostAvailabilityCheck(port).recoverWith(case t:Throwable => acquire(port)).get
}
```

This is a naive implementation as it will trigger an infinite loop waiting for the port to be available and probably attempt to catch unrecoverable errors but it should give you the general idea. 
The implementation can only really be useful if you use 0 as the port value, in which case it will try various random ports until it finds one which is free.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. Option with using `Try` seems to me more elegant, but the problem with it is that Java code automatically closes new Socket (because it uses try-with-resources block). This is was my main problem, i.e. how elegantly convert it to functional style and properly close resource.

Comment: can you clarify that in the question, I'll add a section

Comment: Seems very promising, thanks again, but I still have 1 error: the `opt` method of managed resource is not defined for me. I'm using last version if scala- arm - 1.4

Comment: indeed, for some reason you must map first before you are able to extract. I had a map left over in my sample code wich I edited while pasting in the answer :)

Comment: I didn't know about Scala-arm, thank you. AFAIK: The "traditional" Scala way has been [`using`](https://github.com/jmora/scala.util/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/jmora/scala/util/idioms.scala#L7). I personally prefer the (standard) `Try` monad, but would it close the `Socket` in this case? Also, how does Scala-arm know when to close the resource in the monadic style?

Comment: If I understand correctly scala-arm will close the managed resource on the `opt` or `either` call. it is also able to defer actual evaltuation. for further reference `using` is usually called the `Loan pattern`. scala-arm is a more complete implementation of `using` :)